# Load data after the download from an NSThread in another class

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, nsthread

In my AppDelegate, during the splash screen, i start an NSThread that download data from internet.
When the NSThread finish, i remove the splash screen.

The view that i need to show after the splash screen, use the data downloaded.
The problem is that the method

```
viewWillAppear
```

and

```
viewDidLoad
```

are called during the NSThread... and the app can crash because the data are not completly downloaded!

This is my code (in appdelegate.m)

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {   
      //...
      //... 
      NSThread* parse_thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(carica_dati)  object:nil];
     [parse_thread start];
     return YES;
}

-(void)carica_dati{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
   //download data, then remove the splash screen
   [pool release];
   [NSThread exit];
}
```

how can i solve it?
Is possible call a method when the NSThread finish (but i need to call it in another class, the class of my view)?

Thanks!

Comment: OK, sorry! SOLVED! I add the main view `[self.windows addSubview:tabbar.view]` after the nsthread!

Answer (score 0):

;)

add the main view [self.windows addSubview:tabbar.view] after the nsthread!

;)